# Convert a video to black and white using avidemux on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, colors, video-editing, avidemux

I have a small video that I would like to convert to black and white. I'm on Ubuntu, and I've avidemux installed. I will be OK if it can be done with some other software if not avidemux; basically, using some open source or free software, not a software for which I've to pay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.goitexpert.com/general/convert-video-in-ubuntu/), MEncoder that comes with the MPlayer package is cabable of doing this.

> sudo apt-get install mplayer libxine-extracodecs 
>   mencoder color-video.avi -o black-white-video.avi -vf hue=0:0 -oac copy -ovc lavc

The [manual](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/man/en/mplayer.1.html) and [encoder guide](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/encoding-guide.html) to MEncoder.

Comment: Thanks you!

For some reason, I couldn't install "libxine-extracodecs". So, when I installed just mplayer, I didn't get the mencoder tool. I installed mencoder separately, and executed the second command above. Worked like a charm!